# Considerations in applying machine learning / AI to "coding" of text responses

Tags: text-mining, text-summarization

A client is looking at applying AI/ML to a dataset of textual responses for the purpose of: a) extracting one or more concepts or meanings from each response, and b) cross-referencing with other responses containing similar concepts or meanings.

Having no background in ML, I'm wondering where to point the client, in terms of existing online text analysis services, or code libraries, which could help them assess the requirements for this project.

An example would be a response from someone comenting on their workplace and professional interactions. The client would like to analyse a bunch of these comments and expose common concepts. Examples might be "unsafe workplace" or "job dissatisfaction".

Is this kind of thing - analysing text and exposing common conceptual threads - within the capabilities of existing ML/AI services?